# How to whitelist websites?

Tags: security, browser, parental-control

How would I whitelist so that I can only use certain websites in my browser?

Comment: Try a parental browser I don't Chrome can do this natively.  Alternatively root.  https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=mobicip.com.safeBrowserff&hl=en_US&gl=US

Comment: Which browser are you using? Which Android version and device are you using?